# How to fetch the options and values from a data-list using squish tool in python scripting

Tags: python, automation, squish

I am automating a web application. I have to click on an text box and then I have to select a value from the list-box displayed after clicking on the text-box. Please see the image attached
[image]

This is code I have written :

```
    childObjOfParentDiv= getChildrenObject(eval(parentObj))        
    selectOptionFromList(childObjOfParentDiv[1],"JACK")
```

```
@staticmethod    
    def getChildrenObject(parentObject):
      children = []
      try:
          parentObject = Synchronization.waitForObject(parentObject) 
          for child in object.children(parentObject):
              children.append(child)
      except Exception as err:
          Logger.error("exception message: %s, exception args: %s", err.message, err.args)
      finally:
          return children

@staticmethod
    def selectOptionFromList(parentObject, optionValue, propertyName = 'value', exactMatch = False):

        children = Utilities.getChildrenObject(parentObject)
        for child in children:
            try:
                propertyValue = Utilities.getObjectPropertyValue(child, propertyName).strip()
                if exactMatch and (optionValue == propertyValue):                      
                    Wrapper.mouseClick(child)
                    Synchronization.wait(StaticWait.minWaitInSeconds)
                    break                    
                elif optionValue in propertyValue:                      
                    Wrapper.mouseClick(child)
                    Synchronization.wait(StaticWait.minWaitInSeconds)
                    break
            except Exception as err:
                Logger.error("exception message: %s, exception args: %s", err.message, err.args)
```

But the options from the datalist is not getting picked and the datalist is showing empty

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

Note that entering the to-be-selected datalist entry text is required, because at least Firefox does not seem to report valid screen coordinates for the datalist option elements, and calling the click method of the option elements does not seem to have an effect.

Once the entry text is entered into the input element, the datalist is filtered down to that entry and then the entry can be selected with a mouse click relative to the input element or with key presses.

```
def main():
    startBrowser("https://davidwalsh.name/demo/datalist.php")

    o = waitForObject({"name": "frameworks", "tagName": "INPUT", "type": "text", "visible": True})
    select_datalist_entry(o, "jquery")
    snooze(2)


def select_datalist_entry(input_obj, datalist_entry_text):
    nativeMouseClick(input_obj, MouseButton.LeftButton)
    snooze(0.5)
    nativeType("<Ctrl+a>")
    nativeType("<Delete>")
    snooze(0.5)
    nativeMouseClick(input_obj, MouseButton.LeftButton)
    snooze(0.5)
    nativeType(datalist_entry_text)
    snooze(0.5)
    x = input_obj.x + 5
    y = input_obj.y + (2 * input_obj.height)
    nativeMouseClick(x, y, MouseButton.LeftButton)

    # Alternative approach to select from data list:
    #nativeType("<Down>")
    #snooze(0.5)
    #nativeType("<Return>")
```